# Pass an object from python script to c++

Tags: python, c++

I have a simple c++ code which calls a python script. I was able to return an object from the python script to the c++ code, the problem now is that I can't figure out how to read that object in my c++.

**relevant piece of python script**

```
class obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "hello"
        self.i = 8

class Test():
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
    def finalize(self):
        t = obj()
        print t.msg, t.i
        return t
```

**relevant c++**

```
Py_Initialize();

PyObject *import, *attr, *instance, *methodcall, *arg, *tuple;
PySys_SetPath("./py/");
import = PyImport_ImportModule("script");
attr = PyObject_GetAttrString(import, "Test");
arg = PyString_FromString("arg from first");
tuple = PyTuple_Pack(1, arg);
instance = PyInstance_New(attr, tuple, NULL);

methodcall = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "finalize", NULL);

Py_Finalize();
```

***I would very much appreciate an answer using the default python API (using python.h) not any other library***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a very simple line of code shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/api/object.html), all what I needed to do was to call `PyObject_GetAttrString` with the pyObject as the first argument and the name of the attribute I needed as the second.

In the following piece of code I check whether it exists or not then I print it.

```
PyObject_HasAttrString(methodcall, "msg") ? 
    printf(PyString_AsString(PyObject_GetAttrString(methodcall, "msg"))) :
    printf("ERROR\n");`
```